# How to allow visitors add option in poll?

Tags: 7, polls

I would like to have a poll for logged in and anonymous users to vote. 
In the poll, users are allowed to add in their own poll option and vote. (Just like how Facebook poll is working previously)

Is there any drupal way which I can do this? Or I need to use some combination of ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Advanced Poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/advpoll)

> Advanced Poll is a replacement to Drupal's poll module and provides
> multiple voting systems, decision-making tools, and management
> options.

Then in permissions (`/admin/people/permissions`), allow anonymous and authenticated users to vote and add write in votes.

[image]

Comment: But advance poll does not allow voters to add their own option and vote for that?

Comment: In permissions there is a `Add write in-votes` (2nd last on the picture above)